# Objective-C builtin template system?

Tags: objective-c, file, templates

I am developing an iPhone application and I use HTML to display formatted text.

I often display the same webpage, but with a different content. I would like to use a template HTML file, and then fill it with my different values.

I wonder if Objective-C has a template system similar to ERB in Ruby.

That would allow to do things like

Template:

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <H1>{{{title}}}</H1>
    <P>{{{content}}}</P>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Objective-C (or what it may be in an ideal world)

```
Template* template = [[Template alloc] initWithFile:@"my_template.tpl"];
[template fillMarker:@"title" withContent:@"My Title"];
[template fillMarker:@"content" withContent:@"My text here"];
[template process];
NSString* result = [template result];
[template release];
```

And the result string would contain:

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <H1>My Title</H1>
    <P>My text here</P>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

The above example could be achieved with some text replacement, but that would be a pain to maintain.
I would also need something like loops inside templates. For instance, if I have multiple items to display, I would like to generate multiple divs.

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you considered using as template:

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <H1>%@</H1>
    <P>%@</P>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

And then:

```
// just to get file name right
NSString* fn = 
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/my_template.tpl", 
              [[ NSBundle mainBundle ] resourcePath ]];
// template
NSError *error;
NSString* template = 
    [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fn 
              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
// result
NSString* result = 
    [NSString stringWithFormat:template, 
              @"MyTitle", 
              @"MyText"];
```

I think it's pretty much what you want.

Of course you'll have to add your template files as resources in the project.

Comment: Ho, didn't even thought of using stringWithFormat. That sound good, I'll create a little wrapper around it to create a minimal template system. Thanks!

Comment: Ha, 25 minutes without a reply and then two of the same idea at the same time.

Comment: This is a very dangerous thing to do - especially if the template is not strictly controlled.  Even if it is, you're walking on eggshells.  It's unfortunate this is not often quoted for Objective-C.  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/groue/GRMustache may help you.

Comment: Agreed, GRMustache is extremely helpful when using Web Views in Cocoa.

Answer (score 2):

No, Objective-C has no built-in template system. Generally for simple uses you'd just use textual replacement (possibly via `stringWithFormat:`) and for something more advanced you'd choose a full-fledged template system that suits your needs.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/05/20/mgtemplateengine-templates-with-cocoa/

Comment: Can you please summarize the contents of the link?  Simply posting a link is not helpful.

Comment: Pedantic – It _is_ helpful, but not _as_ helpful ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a lightweight template engine for objective-c : [CCTemplate](https://github.com/xhan/CocoaTemplateEngine)

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3.1

```
var fn: String = "\(Bundle.main.resourcePath)/my_template.tpl"
// template
var error: Error?
var template = try? String(contentsOfFile: fn, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    // result
var result = String(format: template, "MyTitle", "MyText")
```

Answer (score -3):

For many of you likely to be unlikely option, but I needed templates to generate code and chose to use java + ftp, http://freemarker.org/libraries.html

I ended up with a tool to generate tableviews, form views, collection views, google drive integration based on the data model xcdatamodeld file.